# Do I need to update php file because of new php version?

Tags: php

on my website I use 1 php-file for the handling of contact form. My webhost send me a message to say that the php-file is outdated and probably will stop working soon. I'm sorry but my knowledge of php is minimum. How do I update the file to latest php version?
Below you'll find the code.
Thank you, Paul

```
       '<?php

   $where_form_is="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].strrev(strstr(strrev($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),"/"));

session_start();
if( ($_SESSION['security_code']==$_POST['security_code']) && (!empty($_POST['security_code'])) )     { 

$email_to = "info@mysite.com"; 
$mailklant = $_POST['field_2'];
$achternaam = $_POST['field_1'];
$headers = 'From: La Rosiere <info@mysite.com>' . "\r\n" .      
    'Reply-To: info@mysite.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($email_to,"Contact aanvraag Engels","Vraag van klant:

naam: " . $_POST['field_1'] . " 
email: " . $_POST['field_2'] . " 
vraag: " . $_POST['field_3'] . " 

", "$headers");

mail($mailklant,"Your question to La Rosiere.","

Dear Mr/Mrs $achternaam,

Hereby a copy of the submitted data:

name: " . $_POST['field_1'] . " 
email: " . $_POST['field_2'] . " 
question: " . $_POST['field_3'] . " 


We will contact you as soon as possible.

Kind regards,


", "$headers");

include("iconfirmen.html");
}
else {
include ("icaptchaen.html");
}

?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that needs to be updated myself after a quick scan. However you should go through the process of determining this for yourself.

The way you do this is look at what version of PHP you run on your server now.

Then you go through each upgrade guide from one version to the next.

For example if you're running 5.6 you'll want to go through the 5.6 to 7 guide: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php

You're looking for mention of any functions you depend on in your script that have been deprecated and follow the instructions for changing your code to work with the next version.

You then need to repeat this process until you've brought your script up to standards with whichever version of PHP you're upgrading to on your server.

Comment: Hello Dan, 
Thank you for your answer.